# Explanation transitivity of equal coq

Tags: coq, coqide

I have a proof which is already proved.

```
Lemma Equal_Trans : forall T : Type, forall y x z: T, 
      Equal x y -> Equal y z -> Equal x z.
```

And secondly, I have the correction of the addition commutativity proof.

```
Lemma Add_com : forall x x': Nat, Equal (Add x x') (Add x' x).
Proof.
intros.
induction x.
simpl.
apply Add_zero.
simpl.
apply (Equal_Trans Nat (S (Add x' x)) ). (* var y *)
apply Equal_Morph.
assumption.
apply Add_S.
Qed.
```

However, I don't understand the use of Equal_trans (line 8). If I understand, Equal_Trans takes 3 arguments : y x z ? But why there is only 1 argument using Equal_Trans in Add_com lemma ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The tactic `apply` tries to fill in the blanks to match the type of the provided term with the goal. In this case, the goal (when the tactic is used) is probably something along the lines of `a = b` (based on your followup, it's actually `Equal a b`). The type of `Equal_Trans` (when all the arguments are used) is `x = z` (`Equal x z`), so to unify these two types, we should have `x := a` and `z := b`. That only leaves `y` as ambiguous, so we have to provide it.

To address your followup, no, `Equal_Trans` does not take *just* one argument. It takes a type (`Nat` in your case) three elements of that type (`y`, `x` and `z`) and two equality proofs. However, remember that functions in Coq are curried, which means that you can call them with fewer arguments, but the result will be a function of the remaining arguments.

So really, when we say `apply (Equal_Trans Nat (S (Add x' x)).`, we're saying "take this thing that has type `forall (x z: Nat), Equal x (S (Add x' x)) -> Equal (S (Add x' x)) z -> Equal x z` and try to fill in some of the arguments to match it with my goal".

Coq looks at that type and realizes that the goal already looks like `Equal x z`, so it's able to deduce what `x` and `z` have to be. `Equal_Trans` still takes two more arguments that Coq can't figure out on its own (the proofs of `Equal x y` and `Equal y z`), so that's what the rest of the proof is doing.

---

We use transitivity with `y :=  S (Add x' x)` because we can prove `Equal (S (Add x x')) (S (Add x' x))` using the inductive hypothesis (`IHx`). We can also prove `Equal (S (Add x' x)) (Add x' (S x))` by using the definition of `Add`. Hence, it's natural to route the proof of equality through `S (Add x' x)`.

Now, we don't *have* to use transitivity with `y :=  S (Add x' x)`. We could prove that `(S (Add x x'))` and `(Add x' (S x))` are both equal to some other element of `Nat`. But the easiest and most direct route is through `S (Add x' x)`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's really understandable now. Good continuation !

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for help.

If I understand, Equal_trans take just 1 argument, the y argument ?

But, before make the command `apply (Equal_Trans Nat (S (Add x' x)) )`, CoqIDE says me :

```
1 subgoal
x, x' : Nat
IHx : Equal (Add x x') (Add x' x)
______________________________________(1/1)
Equal (S (Add x x')) (Add x' (S x))
```

I don't understand why, here, I must take y := S (Add x' x) to apply Equal_trans ?

Comment: This would be better as an edit to the question. I've added some remarks to my answer.